# node labelling not working d3 v5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts

I am trying to add labels inside my node but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
//draw circles for the nodes
var node = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes_data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr("fill", circleColour);
node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) { return d.name });
```

When I do inspect elements of the node, I can see the text inside the node:

```
<circle r="15" fill="blue" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" cx="421.4930863434973" cy="221.26393165638473"><text dx="12" dy=".35em">some name</text></circle>
```

But it doesn't display in chart. Can anyone please help me here?
Here is the full 
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mZLQw9Yp0PZAfRbQoKQX?p=preview):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per definition circle can have only animation elements and descriptive elements as content. So you cannot put text inside circle.

Solution is to add multiple g elements for each node and then inside it have circle and text elements.

```
var node = g.selectAll('.nodes')
  .data(nodes_data)
  .enter().append('g')
  .attr('class', 'nodes')

node.append('circle')
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr("fill", circleColour)

node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) { return d.name });
```

and then in tick

```
node.attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
```

Here is working forked [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6GqleTU89bSrd9hFQgI2)